# Mongodb match multiple condition

Tags: mongodb

How to filter with multiple condition in mongodb, if bookCode match and stock < 1 the user can borrow the book

[image]

```
const cariBuku = await Book.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {stock: 0}, {code:req.body.kodeBuku}
                ]
            }
        }
    ])

if (!cariBuku) {
        const savedPinjaman = await newPinjaman.save();
        res.status(201).json(console.log(savedPinjaman))
    } else {
        res.send("Mohon maaf buku telah di habis terpinjam")
        
    }
```

But it always end up on else state.

```
Select * from book where stock < 1 and bookCode=bookCode
```

How to do it like that one ^^^^
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code always ends up in the `else` statement because the `Model.aggregate` method will always return an array of 0 or more documents. Therefore your `if (!cariBuku)` will never be true as it looks like you are checking for not `null`. Mongoose only returns a `null` from single queries such as `Model.findById` or `Model.findOne` etc.

The solution to fix that problem would be to check for the array length like so:

```js
if (!cariBuku.length) { //< check that cariBuku.length not 0 
   //..
   //..
} else {
   //...
}
```

As an aside your query would probably have suited a simple `Model.find` like so:

```js
const cariBuku = await Book.find({
   code: req.body.kodeBuku,
   stock: {
      $lt: 1
   },
   // stock: 0  //< You can use $lt or simple equals like this
})
```

The `Model.find` also returns an array of 0 or more documents so the solution will still be the same.